# tf.cond : adding an element to a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a conditional control flow in a very simple graph which enables to add an element to a list. In my case, the list should be declared using the `tf.Variable([])`.

I am getting a weird error : `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list1' referenced before assignment`.

Here is a toy example:

```
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=[])
list1 = tf.Variable([])

def f1():
  e1 = tf.constant(1.0)
  list1 = tf.concat([list1, [e1]], 0)

def f2():
  e2 = tf.constant(2.0)
  list1 = tf.concat([list1, [e2]], 0)

y = tf.cond(pred, f1, f2)
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(y.eval(feed_dict={pred: False}))  # ==> [1]
  print(y.eval(feed_dict={pred: True}))   # ==> [2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf.get_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) Gets an existing variable with these parameters or creates a new one.

So this pattern avoids the problem that you face.

In addition to that I had to use this line after switching off shape validation as that caused validation errors.

```
       list1 = tf.assign( list1, tf.concat([list1, [e1]], 0), validate_shape=False)
```

The working code is this.

```
   def f1():
        with tf.variable_scope("reuse", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            list1 = tf.get_variable(initializer=[], dtype=tf.float32, name='list1')
            e1 = tf.constant(1.)
            print(tf.shape(list1))
            list1 = tf.assign( list1, tf.concat([list1, [e1]], 0), validate_shape=False)
            return list1


    def f2():
        with tf.variable_scope("reuse", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            list1 = tf.get_variable(  dtype=tf.float32, name='list1')
            e2 = tf.constant(2.)
            list1 = tf.assign( list1, tf.concat([list1, [e2]], 0), validate_shape=False)
            return list1


    y = tf.cond(pred, f1,  f2)

    with tf.Session() as session:

      with tf.variable_scope("reuse", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
          session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
          print(session.run([y], feed_dict={pred: False}))  # ==> [1]
          print(session.run([y], feed_dict={pred: True}))  # ==> [2]

          # Gets the updated variable
          list1 = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='list1')
          print(session.run(list1))
```

This prints

```
[array([2.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2., 1.], dtype=float32)]
[2. 1.]
```